# How do you add yourself as "member of the team" in a Facebook page?

Tags: facebook-pages

In Facebook pages, you can add a link to your personal account, under the label "member of the team". I did it once but I don't remember how I did it, I believe Facebook sent me a suggestion to add myself as a member of the team and I just accepted it.

How do you it when you don't get this suggestion, for another Facebook account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the option, here it is

[image]

Comment: That section does not show on my page.

Comment: This is something relatively new. Sometimes it happens that Facebook introduces changes progressively in users. For example, the last interface, "the biography" many friends from other countries had it before I had it. But of course, it could also be another thing. For example, that the category of the page has to be certain category for this option to appear. Or another condition I can't imagine.

Answer (score 5):

Page > About > Team Members > Add yourself as a team member (you have to already be a page admin)

https://www.facebook.com/help/1318804834897643?helpref=search&sr=4&query=add%20to%20team

Comment: this option is no longer available

Answer (score 2):

I also dismissed the first popup where I may add myself as a team member of my  page and tried a lot of things to get facebook to ask me this question again.
I found no solution via setting or anything else, but maybe a workaround:

I tried to share a post from my facebook page to my own member profile. This can be done like described in https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10208221118758828.

Look at the bootom right corner of the post you want to share. In the dropdown select your personal profile. Then push the share button and select share...
In the modal select the dropdown again and make sure that "share in your timeline" is selected, then share the post. It should then be shown in the timeline of your personal profile.

After this, I opened up my facebook page again and suddenly facebook asked me the question again (see screenshot). Now it was possible for me to add/link my own profile as team member for my fb page. Maybe this solution will work for others too.

[image]

Comment: It sounded like something that could actually work, but it didnt at least for me.

Comment: Sorry that my guess didn't work for you. On the same evening when this message popped up, I got more than 10 likes for my page, maybe it is tied to this?

Comment: Maybe this also helps: 
https://ekatcommunication.ch/adding-personal-profile-to-facebook-page/
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/community/question/?id=10207767439735136

Answer (score 2):

The solution that Pablo posted didn't show up on my german fb-page (see screenshot), but I have already linked my profile to the page by having the luck that the popup was displayed randomly.
[image]

It seems that fb works different depending on the language/country?

Comment: Is there any solutions in settings?

Comment: @Nick, see my post below.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr: You can add those pages on your profile at "Manages ..."

On the most recent interface some pages might not have the option to edit Team members. For some of my older pages the Team Members section is available, for newer it is not there (regardless the like count). Interesting that it shows up in the Page Admin app for every page, but not in browser.

Older page with 1 like:
[image: Older pages has "Add yourself as team member"]

Newer page with ~30 likes (it is not even available in the Edit Page section)
[image: Newer pages does not have "Add yourself as team member"]

You can still add yourself by going to your profile. If you have pages you already manage, there will be a "Manages ..." section where you can add pages. You cannot add others, though, but I think it was never an option.

[image: Edit profile page "Manages" section]